# Django translations multiple .mo files

Tags: python, django, internationalization

There are two sets of .po files: one set is created when `./manage.py makemessages` is called, and other is custom made when one of translation scripts.

After debugging, I realized that `GNUTranslation` class sets domain to be `django`, leading to load only django.mo file.

Is there any way to set application to load all .mo files regardless of domain?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, `django` is contract for using `makemessages` command according to [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/translation/#how-django-discovers-translations).

But you can do your own gettext utils for using custom.po with following code:

```
import gettext
import os
from django.conf import settings

t = gettext.translation('your_po_name', settings.LOCALE_DIR, fallback=True)
_ = t.ugettext

message = _('Test!')
print(message)
```